# terminal output from python to excel

Tags: python

I have a terminal output in python as

```
2020
2021
```

This should appear in excel using for loop in python

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: pipe it into a file and open as CSV?

Comment: python3 program.py > myfile.txt then import it into excel